# Header in SOAPclient PHP

Tags: php, soap

I have very little experience with SOAP. How do I specify username and password in a soap client ?
See below the corresponding section of the WSDL.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xx="xx.services.soap">
<soapenv:Header>
  <cb:UserName>_SNIP_</cb:UserName>
  <cb:Password>_SNIP_</cb:Password>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
  <cb:checkOrderable>
     <arg2>
        <EAN>9789084999820</EAN>
        <DeliveryChannel>CBW</DeliveryChannel>
     </arg2>
  </cb:checkOrderable>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have the following code but the server response that username and password are not given:

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://xxxxx...xxxxxService?wsdl");

$params = array(
  "UserName" => "abc",
  "Password" => "def",
  "EAN" => $ean,
  "DeliveryChannel" => "xxx",
);

$response = $client->checkOrderable( $params );
print_r( $response );
```

Comment: Have you reviewed authentication notes in  http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php ?

Comment: I did javabrett. I tried all the examples, no result.

Comment: Can't be no result - what was the result - an auth challenge, 401. 403?  What authentication does the service support, BASIC?

Comment: II tried this:$client = new SoapClient("https://xxxxx...xxxxxService?wsdl",array('UserName' => 'username','Password' => 'Password'));

Comment: Sorry... Result:  stdClass Object ( [Message] => stdClass Object ( [MessageType] => E [MessageCode] => WMS-00005 [MessageText] => No username and/or password provided by the caller. ) )

Comment: Please update the question with that information, it is easier if it is kept there rather that in comments, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `login` and `password` parameters for BASIC auth.  Also worth adding `'trace' => true`.  If your WSDL is password-protected then you will need to pass these to the `SoapClient` constructor.